# What is on port 5298

Tags: networking

Just now,...

Here I found 'samba' daemon running around with my network. Probably some application had it as a dependency. I removed it, after I dropped the two ports in 'iptables'.

```
sudo apt-get remove samba
```

Then I took a quick examination of the system, and found port **TCP/5298** to be open. Nmap calls the service 'presence' which is like... *not the thing* ... to tell paranoid sysops.

WHAT IS RUNNING ON THAT PORT!?; RATHER HOW DO I FIND OUT WHAT IS RUNNING ON THAT PORT?

Comment: Try " netstat -a | grep 5298 " without double quotes in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /proc/5398/cwd
```

will give the path of the running application

as per i know "**nestat -anp | grep 5368**" command  will give you the executable name

Answer (score 0):

Link-local XMPP. Perhaps you have Empathy running?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sure it does. Port 5298 is used for link-local XMPP.

Comment: While this answers the question, a little more explanation on **how** you came to this answer might be useful.